# How to pass data through a table row on clicking it to other component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Im creating a email inbox component for a system, and the list of emails are disposed as a table, so on click it calls to other component. I need to show the infos of the email of the selected row on other component, since it dont render on each other, im just calling using router-link. How is the basic idea to do this? I dont need the final answer, just what i need to do or use to make this kind of task.

Comment: to transfer context you can use an eventbus, vuex, router params, properties, globals, rest ...

Answer (score 0):

User [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) for communication between the child component and the parent. Use [events] [2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) to send data from child to parent.